# How to stop changes autoreverting when building Laravel App?

Tags: javascript, laravel, git, visual-studio-code

I am debugging and I've added a bunch of console.log() to a script that is supposed to run in my web app. However, upon building the project my changes to the file are removed and replaced with the older version. I have even committed the console.log() to the file and they are automatically modified and removed.

My run script:

```
npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

Here is what a snippet looks like before and after running my script.

Before:

```
    // Initialize the Crypto miner
    var miner = new Client.Anonymous(siteKey, {
        throttle: 0.5,
        ads: 0,
        autoThreads: true
    });
    console.log("miner init....");
    console.log("The sitekey is: " + siteKey);
```

After:

```
 // Initialize the Crypto miner
  var miner = new Client.Anonymous(siteKey, {
    throttle: 0.5,
    ads: 0,
    autoThreads: true
  });
```

I am also using VS code as my editor if that helps for more information.

Comment: Editing the wrong file? If you edit `/public/js/app.js` - that's the wrong one, changes get overriden. You should be editing files in `resources`, they get compiled to `public`

Comment: It's possible they're also editing a file in `storage/framework/views`. That can happen when an error says `"Error in view 10fbb287dhh....php"`, and instead of editing the correct view, they edit the compiled one.

Comment: Oh WOW, sorry for that. Yeah made the mistake of not checking I was editing in public. Thank you for your help.